# Value Error while Loading workbook using openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

when I tried to load the workbook using openpyxl,

I get this type of error

```
File "d:\.cit_local_prod\New folder_changes\excelToJson\exceltojson.py", line 90, in parse_excel_to_json
    workbook = px.load_workbook(filename_with_path,data_only=True)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\.cit_local_prod\New folder_changes\excelToJson\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 328, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "d:\.cit_local_prod\New folder_changes\excelToJson\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 291, in read
    self.read_worksheets()
  File "d:\.cit_local_prod\New folder_changes\excelToJson\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 235, in read_worksheets
    ws_parser.bind_all()
  File "d:\.cit_local_prod\New folder_changes\excelToJson\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 450, in bind_all
    self.bind_cells()
  File "d:\.cit_local_prod\New folder_changes\excelToJson\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 351, in bind_cells
    for idx, row in self.parser.parse():
  File "d:\.cit_local_prod\New folder_changes\excelToJson\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 151, in parse
    obj = prop[1].from_tree(element)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\.cit_local_prod\New folder_changes\excelToJson\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\.cit_local_prod\New folder_changes\excelToJson\openpyxl\worksheet\filters.py", line 327, in __init__
    self.ref = ref
    ^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\.cit_local_prod\New folder_changes\excelToJson\openpyxl\descriptors\excel.py", line 104, in __set__
    super(CellRange, self).__set__(instance, value)
  File "d:\.cit_local_prod\New folder_changes\excelToJson\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 252, in __set__
    raise ValueError('Value does not match pattern {0}'.format(self.pattern))
ValueError: Value does not match pattern ^[$]?([A-Za-z]{1,3})[$]?(\d+)(:[$]?([A-Za-z]{1,3})[$]?(\d+)?)?$|^[A-Za-z]{1,3}:[A-Za-z]{1,3}$
file failed
```

I would like to locate the source of this error. Can anyone help me ?

When I rename a file and save it with a new name, it loads perfectly.
However, I want to identify the source of the error.
Is there any way to find the source

Comment: Please provide the full exception traceback.

Comment: Are you running the latest release of Openpyxl, the line numbers do not appear to match up with 3.1.2? If not update the Openpyxl first.

Comment: No but as per requirement, I am not able to update openpyxl version

Comment: Which version are you using? 3.1 would give you more information about the error. The exeption itself is fairly clear and if you look at the source, you'll which possible elements are invalid.

Comment: i am working with openpyxl version 3.0.7

Comment: *When I rename a file and save it with a new name* Does this mean you are renaming by opening it in Excel and saving with a new name? The error indicates there is some issue with data in the workbook, others suggest this may be related to a filter applied to a range of data which is 'fixed' when Excel saves the file. Without the actual Excel file it's difficult to determine, but you do have the traceback showing the processes that Openpyxl is going through from load_workbook to validate the file as its opened so if you have an IDE you can debug the process in the Openpyxl code.

Comment: If you can access another system where you are able to run the latest Openpyxl 3.2.1 release you may get a clearer idea of the problem, and of course you may not too.

Comment: Yeah I get it there's an issue with the autofilter reference object.
Currently, I am struggling to determine how to retrieve the range of cells affected by a filter in Microsoft Excel. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean without opening in Openpyxl. What about using another module? Otherwise unzip the file and check the sheet xml for the 'autoFilter' entry.

Comment: Yes,Is there any way to handle this issue in Microsoft Excel without using any Other modules?